# Города с одинаковым названием, погодный бот

Tags: java, api, openweathermap

Пишу погодного бота, тяну информацию с https://openweathermap.org/ и столкнулся со следующим нюансом.

При поиске на самом сайте, если городов с таким названием больше чем 1, мне выдается информация о них, но когда использую API в формате

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={city}&APPID={your key}
```

мне, соответственно, выдается только один город (очевидно или самый большой или с самым старшим ИД).

Варианта найти какой-либо список городов, по которому банально хоть и затратно можно было бы пробежаться не предоставляется.

Вариант того, что пользователь должен самостоятельно указывать, например, страну не рассматривается, а, наоборот, надо эту информацию собрать и предоставить пользователю возможность конкретизировать свой запрос.

В Сети тоже не нашел решения этого вопроса. Если кто-то сталкивался чем-то подобным или есть мысли/подсказки по моему вопросу — буду очень признателен за любую помощь.

Comment: В [документации](https://openweathermap.org/current#cityid) рекомендуют использовать `city id`, чтобы получить однозначный ответ от API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В соответствии с [документацией](https://openweathermap.org/current#cityid), вы можете получить однозначный ответ от API, если в запросе укажете `city id`. Неудобство такого подхода в том, что вам нужно заранее выкачать список всех городов и их идентификаторы:

> You can make an API call by city ID. List of city ID 'city.list.json.gz' can be downloaded [here](http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/).
> We recommend to call API by city ID to get unambiguous result for your city.

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку!)